# Place admob ad above surfaceview

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I am a beginner in Java and android , and I need to place the admob ad above SurfaceView it is not working .Can someone help me do this ? this is the code of the layout:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a151e3f18d34b57"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

  <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"

      android:src="@drawable/gunmask" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? What do you get?

Comment: ad is working , but it is invisible ? I noticed it from the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put on the relativelayout the `android:orientation` attribute and the `android:layout_below` attribute at your surface.

Below will put the view after the `@id` you set.

I removed `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

   <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a151e3f18d34b57"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

  <SurfaceView
    android:layout_below="@id/adView"
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:src="@drawable/gunmask" />
</RelativeLayout>
```